# How to find a function that maps an element to row number in a triangle of integers?

Tags: functions, computer-science, triangles, integers

This is a triangle of integers

```
0
1      2
3      4      5
6      7      8      9
10     11     12     13     14
........
```

Is there some function that could map an element number to row number(1 based)? 
Here are some examples of different inputs and outputs 
Input(element) -> output(row number)
0 -> 1
1, 2 -> 2 
3, 4, 5 -> 3 
6, 7, 8, 9 -> 4 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14

I can't find a function that relates element to row number, this isn't linear, quadratic, exponential, etc.....

Answer (score 2):

The first number in row $r$ is
$$0+1+\cdots+(r-1)=\frac{r(r-1)}{2}\ .$$
Hence we need to find $r$ such that
$$\frac{r(r-1)}{2}\le n<\frac{r(r+1)}{2}\ .$$
Doing some algebra,
$$r^2-r\le2n\ ,\qquad r^2+r>2n$$
so
$$(2r-1)^2\le8n+1\ ,\qquad (2r+1)^2>8n+1\ .$$
and hence
$$\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}{2}<r\le\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}{2}\ .$$
This means that $r$ is the greatest integer which is less than or equal to the RHS, that is,
$$r=\left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}+1}{2}\right\rfloor\ .$$

Comment: uhhh how did you come up with this?

Comment: See expanded answer.